# Does the event log get an entry when automatic updates are turned off on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

In the event log we see automatic updates installing and rebooting the server. We thought we turned off automatic udpates prior to the last update/reboot events. When you turn off automatic updates, does it write an event to the log? If so, what is the 'source' of the log entry?

Comment: You might notice the lack thereof in Windows->Setup

Comment: Rather than turning Automatic Updates off, you might try disabling the Automatic Updates service. That will ensure that no updates will be downloaded or installed. You can do this via GPO, which will make it much easier to manage if you have more than a few servers.

Comment: I have the same situation. Could you find any solution? I disabled the updates months ago, now my server restarted automatically because of updates and my boss blamed it on me, but I'm sure I disabled the updates.

Answer (score 3):

The Automated Updates client doesn't generate any specific Event Log messages when its configuration is changed. You'll have better luck locating information about how it is behaving in `%SystemRoot%\WindowsUpdate.Log`, where the Automated Updates client puts most of its logging information.